# awk regex and add 1

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, awk

I have a html file with some variable arrays that I need to increment.  I have been doing it by hand - but now is taking up too much of my time. I have been searching and trying to find the correct tool/syntax to do exactly what I want.

say I have:

```
file[0]=["blah0 blah0", "file0.jpg"]
file[1]=["blah1 blah1", "file1.jpg"]
file[2]=["blah2 blah2", "file2.jpg"]
```

What I would like to do is have the script add one to the variable number giving me room to add more variables earlier. I could specify 5 and have the result be

```
file[5]=["blah0 blah0", "file0.jpg"]
file[6]=["blah1 blah1", "file1.jpg"]
file[7]=["blah2 blah2", "file2.jpg"]
```

This is what I have tried so far - but not much luck... as it removes all the square brackets

```
awk -F [\]\[]  '/^file\[[0-9]+\]=/ {$2="["$2+'$userinput'"]";}1' ${workdirect}/index.html > text.txt
```

Any advice???

Comment: Hm. You want to do some addition. I am unaware of a regex which could perform such a thing. Possibly you need to use at least some scripting language.

Comment: Uh, awk *is* a scripting language...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1

awk '/^file/ {
  m = match($0, "\[[0-9]+\]");
  if (m) {
    printf("%s%d%s\n",
           substr($0, 0, RSTART),
           INC + substr($0, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH - 2),
           substr($0, RSTART + 2, length($0) - RSTART))
  }
}' INC=$2 $1

$ foo.sh tmphtml 5
file[5]=["blah0 blah0", "file0.jpg"]
file[6]=["blah1 blah1", "file1.jpg"]
file[7]=["blah2 blah2", "file2.jpg"]
```

Comment: This looks like it will do what I want - but when I run it - after file[14] it starts outputting random numbers 14, 150, 161, 172, 183... Any ideas???

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Change the last substr into `substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH - 1, length($0) - RSTART))` and it will work for all numbers.

Comment: Nice!  And it isn't really your bad - you were going with the information you were given!

Answer (score 1):

Let `script` be

```
#!/bin/bash
inc=$1
while read line; do
  p1=${line%%[*}
  p3=${line#*]}

  p2=${line#*[}
  p2=${p2%%]*}
  p2=$(( ${p2} + $inc ))

  echo $p1[$p2]$p3
done
```

Call `script`

```
$ script offset < inputfile
```

This is just bash, no overhead of externals.

Answer (score 0):

Easier with perl:

```
perl -nle '$n = 5; /(file\[)([[:digit:]]+)(\]=\[.*\])/; print $1, $2 + $n, $3'
```

Comment: Even easier: `perl -pe 's/\d+/$& + 5/e'`

Answer (score 0):

If the first line really begins file[0]= and everything is sequential, then this might work:

```
awk 'sub(/[0-9]+/,'$userinput'+t) {print; t=t+1}' ${workdirect}/index.html > text.txt
```